# Как правильно работать с white-space?

Tags: css3, css, html

Конкретно со свойством: `white-space: pre-wrap`.
Он почему-то дает какие-то непонятные отступы везде, даже для блоков и картинок.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В тексте сохраняются все пробелы и переносы, однако если строка по ширине не помещается в заданную область, то текст автоматически будет перенесен на следующую строку.

Comment: С текстом ясно, как насчет других элементов? Блоков и тд? Они почему-то появляются с отступами

Comment: White-space используется текста, о каких блоках может идти речь?